# Sortable lists with no jQuery UI

Tags: javascript

I need to have lists that are sortable. I made my own jquery plugin that has two methods: .drag() and .drop(). I made my own methods because I need capability with the IOS and Android. I am stuck with sortable, though. My plugin has all the parameters of the jquery draggable and droppable. I need this project to help my team of developers and other people to create interactive web apps. You can use jQuery methods, but only the UI methods to make animations and such.

Comment: This will probably help you immensely: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Comment: here's an execution using sencha working on iOS: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?144737-Ext.tux.EditableList-Improved-list-component